# Adding the value to each row of data frame, given a vector of names of columns

Tags: r

I'm writing my `predict` function for a list of classification models, so each model would vote for some prediction.

I've created the following function, but it's very slow. The inner most `for` loop takes ages to compute.

```r
predict.risemble <- function(.models, .dataset) {
  all_levels <- unique(unlist(lapply(.models, function(x) x$levels)))
  voting_df <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = length(all_levels), nrow = nrow(.dataset)))
  colnames(voting_df) <- all_levels
  voting_df <- as_tibble(voting_df)
  for (model in .models) {
    cat(sprintf("Making predictions for model %s\n", model$method))
    predictions <- predict(model, .dataset)
    cat("Voting ...\n")
    for (i in 1:length(predictions)) {
      prediction <- as.character(predictions[i])
      voting_df[i, prediction] <- voting_df[i, prediction] + model$results$Kappa
      if (mod(i, 1000) == 0) {
        cat(sprintf("%f%%\n", i / length(predictions) * 100))
      }
    }
  }
  return (as.factor(colnames(voting_df)[apply(voting_df, 1, which.max)]))
}
```

I need to speed up the inner most `for` loop.

So, given a vector of predictions (class `factor`) we can convert it to list of names of columns (class `character`) using `as.character`. Let's call this vector `predictions`.

I need to add some specific value to each row of `voting_df` given a vector of columns `predictions`.

Example:

```r
predictions <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c")
```

```
> voting_df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0
2     1     0     0
3     1     0     0
4     0     1     0
5     0     0     1
```

---

**Edit**
The final version of my `predict` function is this:

```r
predict.risemble <- function(.models, .dataset) {
  all_levels <- unique(unlist(lapply(.models, function(x) x$levels)))
  voting_df <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = length(all_levels), nrow = nrow(.dataset)))
  colnames(voting_df) <- all_levels
  voting_df <- as_tibble(voting_df)
  voting_df <- voting_df %>% select(noquote(order(colnames(voting_df))))
  for (model in .models) {
    predictions <- as.character(predict(model, .dataset))
    votes <- tibble(prediction = predictions) %>%
      mutate(prediction_id = row_number(), value = model$results$Kappa) %>%
      spread(prediction, value) %>%
      select(-one_of("prediction_id"))
    votes[, all_levels[!all_levels %in% names(votes)]] <- NA
    votes <- votes %>% select(noquote(order(colnames(votes))))
    votes[is.na(votes)] <- 0
    voting_df <- voting_df + votes
  }
  return (as.factor(colnames(voting_df)[apply(voting_df, 1, which.max)]))
}
```

Comment: I'm writing my own `predict` function, because `caretEnsemble` requires `savePredictions` in training. But I already have trained models. I won't re-run training as it took me in total 72 hours to train all of my models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to build a dataframe from your vector and then use tidyrs spread function:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(pred =predictions) %>%
mutate(pred_id = row_number(), value =1) %>%
spread(pred, value)
```

Then maybe replace the NAs by zeros. Does that work for your purpose?